# Is there a function in the package lpsolve/lpsolveAPI that is able to remove constraints not met (in case of infeasibility)?

Tags: r, lpsolve

I am using the packages lpSolve and lpSolveAPI in R for linear programmation.

I end up with infeasible models. So, I would like to know if there exists a function that finds the constraints that are not met and that tests with differents set of constraints to get a feasible model.
I have looked at the lpSolveAPI documentation (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lpSolveAPI/lpSolveAPI.pdf) and I wonder if the lp.control.options could help me, but I do not understand the provided explainations.

Plus, I can't do it manually because I have too many constraints.

Thanks if someone understood my problem and could help me.

Comment: See http://lpsolve.sourceforge.net/5.5/Infeasible.htm

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this? I cannot conceive a situation where just blindly throwing away all infeasible constraints is a good idea.

Comment: I'm working with nutritional constraints to optimize food consumption. The contraints are the nutritional recommandations. There are around 100 constraints on nutrients and I just wanna know which constraints on which nutrient implies infeasibility.

Comment: This is not unique. Finding all possible combinations of constraints that make a problem infeasible is a daunting task.

Comment: Finally, I've used the elastic variables methodology, but yes, I'm aware that the solution it gives is not unique. Thanks for your help !